# Listen to popstate and prevent React Router to acts on it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using `history.pupState` in my React router application to make changes in the browser history without changing Router location, so I can only change my popup, it works but when my history state change I can't prevent React Router to change the location. Does a function like `beforePopState` in the next/router exist in React Router v6 ?

Here my code where `handleClose` close the popup, `handleAdd` add or edit the popup, and `data` contains the popup information.

```
const handleChange = useCallback(
        async (e: PopStateEvent) => {
            const pathname = window.location.pathname
            // The close works
            if (!pathname.startsWith("/title/") && data) handleClose()
            else if (pathname.startsWith("/title/")) {
                // It's not working
                e.stopPropagation()

                // I get the id from pathname (eg: "/title/123")
                const id = parseInt(pathname.match(/\d+/g)?.[0]!)
                if (isNaN(id)) return

                const embed = await titleEmbed(id).then(parseResponse)

                if (!embed && data) handleClose()
                else if (embed) handleOpen(embed, { withoutAnimation: true })
            }
        },
        [handleOpen, data, handleClose]
    )

useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("popstate", handleChange)
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("popstate", handleChange)
        }
    }, [handleChange])
```

The thing is I can't create a route for the popup because the popup is used in different routes and it will only get the user back to homepage when reloading the page.

Comment: No, not really. RRDv6 has moved in the direction of extremely proxying "access" to the "history", and it doesn't appear they support blocking navigation either. You can listen to the navigation changes and action type, etc, and issue side-effects though. What exactly is the overall use case here? What is the end goal? Can you describe the behavior/UX you want?

Comment: A popup can be created from each routes (it will change the history), from this popup you can go into an other popup (it will push in to history) and if you go back or next in the history I listen to popstate to change the popup content. If the user refresh when the popup is open it will go to home page and open the popup

Comment: Do you need to mutate the history though? I'm trying to understand the logic for what you are wanting/trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes because if the user go back in his history I need the popup to change to the previous without changing route